# How to order a set of objects based on association attributes in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

In my Ruby on Rails application, I have a model which has a number of one-to-one associations with other models. Let's say each `Instance` belongs to a `Region`, a `Country`, and a `City`. I have selected a couple of `Instance` using a `scope` and now I want to order them based on the `name` attributes of `Region`, `Country`, and `City` models which are not part of the `Instance` model itself.

The thing is that I want to show the selected `Instances` on index action of an ActiveAdmin page by `Region`, `Country`, and `City`, and accordingly, I want to have them sorted in this order.

Answer (score 2):

It's very straightforward to order a collection by attributes on one or more associations—join on the associations and order by their attributes. The verbose way would be like this:

```
Instance.joins(:region, :country, :city).
  order("regions.name DESC").
  order("countries.name DESC").
  order("cities.name DESC")
```

But I would recommend writing these conditions as scopes on your models. Then you can change and reuse them more easily.

```
class Instance < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :ordered, -> do
    joins(:region, :country, :city).
    merge(Region.ordered).
    merge(Country.ordered).
    merge(City.ordered)
  end
end

class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :ordered, -> do
    order(name: :desc)
  end
end

class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :ordered, -> do
    order(name: :desc)
  end
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :ordered, -> do
    order(name: :desc)
  end
end
```

The magic here is in the `merge` method, documented [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge).

Put it together like

```
@instances = Instance.ordered
```